# Prove that for any $1 < p < ∞$ there exists a function $f ∈ L_p(μ)$ such that $f \notin L_q(μ)$ for any $q > p.$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $(X, Ω, μ)$ be a finite measure space.

Assume that for any $t > 0$ there exists $E ∈ Ω$ satisfying
$0 < μ(E) < t.$
Prove that for any $1 < p < ∞$ there exists a function $f ∈ L_p(μ)$ such that $f \notin L_q(μ)$ for any
$q > p.$

I am having trouble starting this problem.  It is the second part to another question on a past qual.  Any help would be awesome.  Thanks.

Comment: I would try something like this: for each sequence $t_n\to 0$, you can find a sequence $E_n$ such that $0<\mu(E_n)<t_n$ and $E_n\cap E_m=\emptyset$ for $n\neq m$. Let $a_n\to 0$ and consider the function $$f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_n\chi_{E_n}(x)$$ I think it is possible to find $t_n$ and $a_n$ satisfying your thesis.

Comment: How do we know we can choose the sets so the intersetion is empty?

Answer (score 2):

We can use Tomás' idea: define 
$$f(x)=\sum_{j=1}^{+\infty}b_n\mu(A_n)^{1/p}\chi(A_n)$$
where the sets $A_n$ are such that $\mu(A_n)\in (0,t_n)$ and $b_n$ is positive. 
If $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}b_n$ is convergent, then $f$ belongs to $\mathbb L^p$. 
We have to choose $t_n$ such that the sequence $(b_n/t_n^r)_{n\geqslant 1}$ does not converge to $0$ for each positive $r$.

Comment: How do you find  function $f \in L_p(μ)$ such that $f \ni L_q(μ)$ for any q<p.